# Универсальный редирект с «//» в любой части URL в nginx

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx, redirect

Возможно ли обратывать запросы такого, т.е. если есть `//` в URL, заменять его на `/`

https://www.itc-life.ru//test/site -> https://www.itc-life.ru/test/site

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes

Comment: не подходит, не убирает // в uri